# Как передать Значение(Float,int.bool) в функцию которая принимает UnsafeMutableRawPointer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я создаю коннект IOS c s7-300 контроллером. коннект есть но не могу корректно передать значение типа Float, У меня возникает вопрос с UnsafeMutableRawPointer! как туда записать float Значение.

Код: Cli_DBWrite(Client:S7Object,DBNumber:Int32,Size:Int32,pUsrData:*UnsafeMutableRawPointer)

Cli_DBWrite(Client,1000,4,4,????) как сюда записать значение Float подскажите пожалуйста UnsafeMutableRawPointer.

Comment: а зачем тот же вопрос опять задавать?

Comment: Я не знал как до Вас достучаться Max

Comment: Я попробовал через bitPattern не получается